# To plot PPI (Protein-Protein interaction graph) and calculate PPI distance in python

Tags: python, igraph

I want to plot the PPI graph and then calculate the PPI minimum distance in igraph. I am running this code in Jupyter notebook and I am getting no error but the distancee matrix is also not generated.

My input file "PPI_links.tsv" looks like (header)

```
ARF5    ACTR10
ARF5    ACTR1A
ARF5    ANK1
ARF5    ANK2
ARF5    ANK3
```

Here is my code:

```
import igraph
import pandad as pd

#import input file
ppi_file = pd.read_csv("PPI_links.tsv", sep="\t", header=None)

#define edges
edges = [line.strip().split("\t") for line in open("PPI_links.tsv")]
vertices = list(set(edge[0] for edge in edges))
edges = [(edge[0], edge[1]) for edge in edges if edge[0] < edge[1]]

# Build graph with graph
graph = igraph.Graph(directed=False)
graph.add_vertices(vertices)
graph.add_edges(edges)
return graph.simplify(combine_edges="max")

# Compute PPI distances (the minimum distances calculated between the target gene and featured genes)

graph = get_PPI_graph("PPI_links.tsv")
genes = list(set(gene_feature_info.index.unique()).intersection(set(graph.vs["name"])))
feature_genes = list(set(gene_feature_info["Feature Gene"].dropna().unique()).intersection(set(graph.vs["name"])))
distance_matrix = graph.shortest_paths(source=feature_genes, target=genes)
distances = dict(
    (feature_gene, dict((gene, distance) for gene, distance in zip(genes, distances)))
        for feature_gene, distances in zip(feature_genes, distance_matrix)
)
```

Comment: Please share your expected output for your post. Thank you

Comment: Your code is either incomplete or you aren't even calling the function? It's hard to know which it is and advise you because you didn't provide working code. For example, there's no import statements. Because you have `ppi_file.head()` randomly as second line, I'm going to assume you were developing this in Jupyter. Always check your code block is a minimal reproducible example, by resarting your kernel and running the code you'll share.

Comment: Also, keep straight where you want to pass the file name or the dataframe. For example, `get_PPI_graph(ppi_file)` looks like it should be using the file name and not the dataframe, `ppi_file`, you made already. And from what you've provided it is unclear where `gene_feature_info` comes form.

Comment: @Wayne: I have now corrected my code. I want distance matrix and distances as output

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew The out put will look like.  

A  B  C  D  E  F
A  NA  1  1  2  2  3

B  1 NA  1  1  1  2

C  1  1 NA  2  2  3
D  2  1  2 NA  2  3
E  2  1  2  2 NA  1
F  3  2  3  3  1 NA

Comment: Overlooking the typo `pandad`,I don't see how you say you fixed your code? Now `get_PPI_graph()` isn't defined but you are calling it? (Plus you still have the return statement from the now-deleted function) It is unclear how `feature_genes = list(set(gene_feature_info["Feature Gene"].dropna().unique()).intersection(set(graph.vs["name"])))` works with what you've shared. Should columns from `"PPI_links.tsv"` have labels?